# Insufficient quota of vCPUs available after creating a VM, imaging it, and then deleting it

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-machine, azureportal

I am testing out Azure VMs as a disaster recovery option for my organization.  I'm on an Azure AD trial.  My use case is this: Ideally, I'd like to have an image standing by with all the software that my users need, pre-installed, and hooked up to our Azure AD domain.  Then, if we should need our DR environment, I'd like to spin up 1..n VMs from the image, send my users the RDP connection files, have them log in with their Office 365 credentials (we also subscribe to Azure AD Premium P1), and get back to work using OneDrive.

I created a VM and populated it with the settings and software I need for my users.  It has a local admin, and I confirmed I could log in using my Azure AD credentials.  Then I ran sysprep /generalize and created an image of the virtual workstation.  So far so good.  As I could no longer access the original VM, I deleted it.  The original VM was of the DS3_v2 size.

Now I'm going to create a new VM from my image to test.  In the Azure portal, I go to Virtual Machines -> Add.  I select my image and Resource Group.  However, when I go to select a Size, I get the following error message:

"4 vCPUs are needed for this configuration, but only 0 vCPUs (of 4) remain for the Standard DSv2 Family vCPUs."  I cannot select any of the available options.  The "Troubleshoot" link directs me to a page instructing me to request a quota increase, but that shouldn't be necessary; I de-allocated [edit: deleted] the old VM and its 4 vCPUs so I could create a new one.  Why is Azure telling me I only have 0 vCPUs left in my trial subscription?

Comment: You say you deleted the VM, but later you say you de-allocated it, which one is it? Does the VM object still exist, even if it is turned off?

Comment: @SamCogan, sorry for that -- I deleted it, not deallocated it.  It's gone from the console.  The console still reads $199.98 in free credit...

Comment: Just coming back to this incase anyone ends up here because Microsoft are pushing back on quota increases due to cornavirus. Who would have thought it would have hit this area. I know this post is about deleting a VM but one ends up here Googling in whether stopping (deallocating) a VM frees up vcpu quota. My experience today is that it *doesn't* - at least not immediately. This could be by design, i.e. you could have a stopped VM on standby. If it needed more quota to bring online, your DR plan would be impacted if it didn't have enough quota

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This morning when I tried again, the console allowed me to select a size.  It appears that there is a very substantial delay between when you delete the VM and when Azure marks the vCPUs as available to use once again.

Comment: Thx for sharing. Happening to me when I deleted a VM and tried to recreate it as a data science VM of the same type: "24 vCPUs are needed for this configuration, but only 0 vCPUs (of 0) remain for the Standard NCSv3 Family vCPUs." Strange that it says "(of 0)" because I was able to create a VM of this type before which has 24 cores.

Comment: After I filled out other fields like "VM Name", Region, etc., the error message went away and I could pick this VM size.

Comment: FYI, the quota are per region so if you're in a hurry then selecting another region might help